emqx loses connection when push multiple messages simultaneously without wait ack
With default config of EMQX. I have isue when push message to topic
When i use golang to push multiple 1000 message with size is 100Kb/ message to topic without wait ACK or use goroutine send simultaneously. If I wait for ack then all are fine but it so long (100Kb/message)
So I don't know what is the best way to handle push messages to topics?
In case I try in local :

Wait ACK: 1000 message, size: 100Kb/message, ==> 8s
Without wait ACK : 1000 message, size: 100Kb/message ==>  lost connection
goroutine + Wait ACK : 1000 message, size: 100Kb/message ==>  lost connection

